# C#/.NET - Create a local webserver without needing admin rights

Tags: c#, webserver, owin

I'm currently trying to create a way to stream local files to a Chromecast.

My question is: Is there anyway to run my C# webserver without needing admin rights, whilst still being available within the network, accessible by that machines IP? i.e. I want to be able to reach my server by visiting `http://192.168.1.10:8080/Whatever`

As of right now, I have the web server which hosts the static (music) files using OWIN, however the issue I'm facing is that without admin rights, I can only bind the webserver to `localhost`. The issue with this is that the Chromecast (obviously) won't be able to resolve the address unless instead of localhost, I bind the address to the machines IP. However for that I need admin rights.

I've tested running the program as an admin and it's confirmed that I'm able to connect by inputting the machine IP + Port #.

I'm wondering if there's maybe an alternative approach I can take as I've though over this for a bit but can't really think of anything else.